Azure App Service only log from code and nothing else?
I have my first App Service website in Azure running a Blazor Server app. I’m sending the logs to Application Insights, however, I wanted to see if there is a way that I can only capture logs that would come from the application code and not all the system logs.
I would also be okay if I had to log everything if there is a way that I can narrow down only User logs in my KQL query.
I have Function Apps that I’m logging more than just my user coded logs but I’m able to use the following in my KQL to only pull logs that were created from within the code. Unfortunately, it doesn’t look like the logs from an App Service have the Category property in the Custom Dimensions.
| where customDimensions["Category"] has "User"

Here is what I have in my appsettings for logging.
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  }
},
"ApplicationInsights": {
  "ConnectionString": "connctionstring info”
}

Creating logs by injecting the ILooger on the Razor page. Here is my Using statement and how I log.
@inject ILogger<Index> _log

_log.LogInformation("Initializing Index page.");



Azure App Service only log from code and nothing else?

To log Information, Critical, Error, Warning traces from code, you can use below code:
Counter.razor:
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject ILogger<Counter> RithLogger
<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        RithLogger.LogInformation("Incremented");
        RithLogger.LogCritical("Hello");
        RithLogger.LogWarning("Hi");
    }
}

appsettings.json:
{
"Logging": {
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Error"
    }
  },
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
  }
},
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"ApplicationInsights": {
  "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=c8db5a66;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=8f2fc3a9"
}
}

csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <ApplicationInsightsResourceId>/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5a074c23f/resourceGroups/bojja/providers/microsoft.insights/components/rith234</ApplicationInsightsResourceId>
    <UserSecretsId>ca6daa64</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Local Logs:

Then connected to Azure Application Insights:

Azure Logs:
traces


Thanks for the info. In your example, your traces are only showing what your code added to the logs which is what I'm looking for. However, I'm seeing a whole bunch of HTTP logging. Way more than just what I'm putting in through code. I've set my logging settings in my appsettings just like your example (with my App Insights connection). I can't seem to upload a screen shot in a comment to show you.

I get things like "Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://mywebsitename." When I run just "traces" for the last 4 hours, I get over 30k records. I'm trying to weed all but what I write to the logs in code.

Hi @Caverman, I didnt get any extra information, I have only used the code which i provided and Only got the needed. If you run last 4 hrs then you will all previous logs too right. Run like  traces|where timestam > ago(1m) something like this to get logs after you have used my code.  I would suggest you try creating a new blazor app and reconnect to a new appinsights service and check it, might be the previous changes are still working.

If you use this {       "Logging": {         "LogLevel": {           "Default": "Information",           "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"         }       },       "AllowedHosts": "*",       "ApplicationInsights": {         "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=c8da66;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=8f2ffc3a9"       } } only the Logs above Information log level will work.
